# Compare saved date field with new unsaved object

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm triying to update a record if the date is the same.

To do that, I retrieve the last record using:

```
saved_object = TheModel.objects.latest("date")
new_object  = TheModel.objects.create(date="2014-12-15")
```

And then I compare the dates using:

```
if saved_object.date == new_object.date:
    doStuffWithTheSavedObject()
    saved_object.save() # update
else:
    new_object.save() # insert new one
```

Looking at the database, I see that the dates are the same so the if statement is returning false. After debuggin it, I see that the new_object.date is a str and not a date type as I thought it should be.

My question is, how can I prepare the new_object so it has a date field with the right type without saving it into the database and without passing it a casted date manually.

Regards

Update:

```
class TheModel(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    a = models.IntegerField()
    b = models.IntegerField()
    c = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: Provide the code for `TheModel` please.

Comment: The code for TheModel is not relevant. Just a couple of int fields among the date field

Comment: FYI `objects.create` already saved the object to db, there is no need to call `save`. You need to instantiate a model instance instead of using `create` and call `save` later on instance.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Aamir. But, anyway, do I need to save the object to be able tu use the date field as a datetime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `datetime.date` or `datetime.datetime` (for DateField or DateTimeField accordingly):

```
import datetime
new_object = TheModel(date=datetime.date(2014, 12, 15))
```

if you have date as string on input, use `strptime`

```
new_object = TheModel(
    date=datetime.datetime.strptime('2014-12-15', '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Comment: If you define a DateField or DateTimeField as a string, when you save it and retrieve it again, you get a datetime object. I want to define a DateField as string and then, get it converted into datetime automagically. Is that possible without saving and using the datetime constructor?